# Rendering Issue with flask

Tags: python, flask, plotly

Below is my snippet which is using python + flask + plotly, it doesn't render a graph but show js code. Surprisingly, for another snippet below (snippet 2) graph loads fine. Any pointer what is wrong on the first one?? :

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

def create_scatter_trace(x, y, name, color, dash_style=None):
    return go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode="lines",
        name=name,
        line=dict(shape="spline", color=color, width=2, dash=dash_style),
        hovertemplate="%{y}",
        showlegend=False
    )

def linechart_graphs(df):
    fig_occ = go.Figure()

    fig_occ.add_trace(create_scatter_trace(df['Future Months'], df["future_data"], "future_data", "red"))

    return fig_occ

class LineChartResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('country', type=str, help='Invalid country', required=False)
        parser.add_argument('state', type=str, help='Invalid state', required=False)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        listing_id = args['country']
        pms = args['state']

        today = pd.Timestamp.today()
        future_months = [today + pd.DateOffset(days=i * 30) for i in range(12)]
        future_data = [50 + i for i in range(12)]

        data = {
            'Future Months': [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt in future_months],  # Convert datetime to formatted string
            'future_data': future_data,
        }

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        fig = linechart_graphs(df)

        chart_div = fig.to_html()

        # HTML content with embedded Plotly chart
        html_content = f"""
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Trends Chart</title>
            <!-- Include Plotly.js library -->
            <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Trends Chart</h1>
            <div>
                {chart_div}
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
        return render_template_string(html_content)

api.add_resource(LineChartResource, '/line_chart')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Snippet 2: Surprisingly, this loads fine totally. Why above doesn't work and this works?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)

def create_scatter_trace(x, y, name, color, dash_style=None):
    return go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode="lines",
        name=name,
        line=dict(shape="spline", color=color, width=2, dash=dash_style),
        hovertemplate="%{y}",
        showlegend=False
    )

def linechart_graphs(df):
    fig_occ = go.Figure()

    fig_occ.add_trace(create_scatter_trace(df['Future Months'], df["future_data"], "future_data", "red"))

    return fig_occ

@app.route('/')
def line_chart_page():
    today = pd.Timestamp.today()
    future_months = [today + pd.DateOffset(days=i * 30) for i in range(12)]
    future_data = [50 + i for i in range(12)]

    data = {
        'Future Months': [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt in future_months],  # Convert datetime to formatted string
        'future_data': future_data,
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Create the line chart figure using the custom layout
    fig = linechart_graphs(df)

    # Convert the Plotly figure to an HTML div element
    chart_div = fig.to_html(full_html=False)

    # HTML content with embedded Plotly chart
    html_content = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Trends Chart</title>
        <!-- Include Plotly.js library -->
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Trends Chart</h1>
        <div>
            {chart_div}
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    return render_template_string(html_content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: The one that works uses `fig.to_html(full_html=False)`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: No, that is not an issue, it was same before. I changed while trying.

Comment: The thing is that Flask views do not have to return response objects but can return a value that is converted into a response object by Flask itself. By using flask_restful Api (which is not meant to handle html page rendering) you would need to be explicit about that (that is, returning a Response with html content) : `return make_response(render_template_string(html_content), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})`.